# webpack-dev-server didn't output any file, but webpack will

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I use `webpack-dev-server -w`, no file generated(even the `public` folder didn't created), but if I use `webpack` then it works well.

This is the example config file:

```
const sysPath = require('path');

config = {
  entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:9090",
    './index.js',
    "webpack/hot/dev-server"
  ],
  resolveLoader: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: []
  },
  output: {
    path: sysPath.resolve('./public'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And I tried the node.js API, it didn't work also.

This is the example project: https://gist.github.com/bolasblack/7c45314b790f35b5632f146a9cebb0ee

Is options or other things I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack Dev server works in-memory. Try browsing to `http://localhost:9090/[bundle]`, where `[bundle]` is the name of your generated file

**Edit:** Noticed your were running on port 9090 and not the default 8080